# Is there any way to overwrite the default operation id , tag, name ,description of generated drf api schema?

Tags: django, schema, drf-spectacular

Is there any way to overwrite the default operationid,name,tag,type,summary, description of generated drf api schema?
When use drf-yasg or drf-spectacular，
is there any way to overwrite the default description shown in the sample picture
or does drf-yasg or drf-spectacular provide other language support for the default description?

I tried i18n support of drf-spectacular but I think it's not for this problem.
And to change the language_code settings of django is not work.

I appriciate your help very much
generated schema is :

````
Schema
GET /schema
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/vnd.oai.openapi
Vary: Accept

openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: Persons
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /persons:
    get:
      operationId: listPersonApis
      description: Get list of persons
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items: {}
          description: ''
      tags:
      - persons
    post:
      operationId: createPersonApi
      description: ":Process: Post a Person \n:summary: \"Create New User\"\n:method:\
        \ `POST`\n:HTTPRequest:\n\n** Context **\n\n:firstName:          `string`\n\
        :lastName:           `string`\n:email:              `string`\n:Response: `Posted\
        \ Data in Json`"
      parameters: []
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema: {}
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema: {}
          multipart/form-data:
            schema: {}
      responses:
        '201':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {}
          description: ''
      tags:
      - persons
  /persons/{id}/:
    get:
      operationId: retrievePersonDetail
      description: ":Process: Person details\n:method: `GET`\n:HTTPRequest:\n    \
        \   \n\n** Context **\n:param: `id`\n\n:Response: `Retrieve List of Json Array\
        \ Data by ID, And Status Code According method`"
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        description: ''
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {}
          description: ''
      tags:
      - persons
    put:
      operationId: updatePersonDetail
      description: ':Process: Person details

        :method: `PUT`

        :HTTPRequest:


        ** Context **

        :param: `id`


        :Response: `Retrieve List of Json Array Data by ID, And Status Code According
        method`'
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        description: ''
        schema:
          type: string
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema: {}
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema: {}
          multipart/form-data:
            schema: {}
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            application/json:
              schema: {}
          description: ''
      tags:
      - persons
    delete:
      operationId: destroyPersonDetail
      description: ':Process: Person details


        :method: `DELETE`

        :HTTPRequest:


        ** Context **

        :param: `id`

        :"description": "Remove person specified by id"'
      parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        required: true
        description: ''
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        '204':
          description: ''
      tags:
      - persons

but this schema should be in this format:final schema**


{
  "openapi": "3.0.3",
  "info": {
    "title": "Persons",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:3000"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/persons/{id}": {
      "parameters": [
        {
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": "id",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true
        }
      ],
      "get": {
        "summary": "Get User Info by User ID",
        "tags": [],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "User Found",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                },
                "examples": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "User Not Found"
          }
        },
        "operationId": "get-persons-id",
        "description": "Retrieve entry for person with the specified id (still delivered as a single entry inside an array)"
      },
      "delete": {
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "delete-persons-id",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "Remove person specified by id"
      },
      "put": {
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "put-persons-id",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "Update person specified by id",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Person"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/persons": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Create New User",
        "operationId": "post-persons",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "User Created",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                },
                "examples": {}
              }
            }
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Missing Required Information"
          },
          "409": {
            "description": "Email Already Taken"
          }
        },
        "description": "Create a new person.",
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Person"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "parameters": [],
      "get": {
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "get-persons",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "Get list of persons"
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Person": {
        "title": "Person",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "readOnly": true
          },
          "first_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "email"
          }
        },
        "x-examples": {
          "example-1": {
            "id": 0,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Smith",
            "email": "user@example.com"
          }
        }
      },
      "Result": {
        "title": "Result",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
              "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Person"
            }
          },
          "error": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "object literal holding error messages keyed to either a field name or \"non_field_errors\" if not applicable\n\n```json\n{\n  \"first_name\": [\"required field\"],\n  \"non_field_errors\": [\"something more general went wrong\"]\n}\n```"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "data"
        ],
        "x-examples": {
          "Example": {
            "data": [
              {
                "id": 0,
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Smith",
                "email": "user@example.com"
              }
            ],
            "error": {}
          },
          "Error-example": {
            "data": [],
            "error": {
              "first_name": [
                "This field is required"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
````

I have created api using class based api view.
how to override schema this in django rest api like as below json format???

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: how to override operation id and schema, tag,summary ,description .like generated operationId: listPersonApis but it should be "operationId": "get-persons", "get": {
        "summary": "",
        "operationId": "get-persons",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Result"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "description": "Get list of persons"
      }
    }
  },

Comment: if anyone help me it will be useful for me. @Swift

Comment: I think you need to override the schema generator, it's not very well documented I think though :(